# FFmpeg encoder metadata field change?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

FFMpeg transcoded prores files show up in Quicktime as ProRes422, but within Premiere they are showing "Lavc57.107.100 prores" in the Compressor metadata field which seems to be the encoder metadata of the file. Is there anyway for me to change the encoder metadata of a file? I want it to represent the more "common" name of the file such as what Quicktime shows.

I have attempted to do -metadata encoder='ProRes422' and also attempted to map_metadata from another file but both of those don't seem to work.

The actual string I've used is:

ffmpeg -i in.mp4 --c:v prores -profile:v 0 -metadata encoder='ProRes422' test2.mov

and similar with the map_metadata line as well.

Answer (score 1):

The encoder tag has to be assigned to the video stream.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v prores -profile:v 0 -metadata:s:v encoder='ProRes422' test2.mov
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks for that tip!

Comment: That does not change the top encoder tag only the stream specific encoder tag. ffmpeg still inserts an "encoder" metatag on top which doesn't seem to be changeable